# Time complexity of a function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, performance, oop, time-complexity, big-o

I have 2 functions which perform same task of identifying if the 2 lists have any common element between them. I want to analyze their time complexity.

What i know is: for loop if iterated n times gives O(n) complexity. But, I am confused with the situation when we use 'in' operator. eg: if element in mylist

Please look at the functions to have better understanding of the scenario:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
list2 = ['m','n','o','d']


def func1(list1, list2):
  for i in list1:      # O(n), assuming number of items in list1 is n
    if i in list2:     # What will be the BigO of this statement??
      return True
  return False

z = func1(list1, list2)
print(z)
```

I have another function func2, please help determine its BigO as well:

```
def func2(list1, list2):
  dict = {}
  for i in list1:
    if i not in dict.keys():
      dict[i] = True

  for j in list2:
    if j in dict.keys():
      return True
  
  return False

z = func2(list1, list2)
print(z)
```

What is the time complexity of func1 and func2? Is there any difference in performance between 2 functions?

Comment: Note that the second function should use a ``set`` instead of a ``dict`` (and not use the type name as an identifier). While ``dict`` keys behave set-like, having the dummy values is wasteful for this purpose and ``set`` is better optimised for membership tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Regarding `func1`:

- searching in lists is a linear operation with respect to the number of elements,
- assuming items are randomly ordered and order of checking is also not related then statistically you come across an existing element in n/2 steps and n when not found (which simplifies to O(n))

`if x in list_` is a linear search as described above, hence `func1` has complexity of n^2.

##### Regarding `func2`:

instead of dictionary you may want to consider using a set. It has O(1) complexity for checking the existence of element. which would improve the complexity over `func1`, and also you can use `set(list)` to create a list instead of iterating over list directly in python (which is slower than initialization of a set directly from list - but does not affect the O complexity, as it is just slower, but constant).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I just saw on "https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity" that checking the existence of element (say, x in my_set) in a set has a worst case complexity of O(n). If thats so, even second function has complexity of O(n^2). Please correct me if i am missing something?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the set, and even then, don't confuse the average case with the worst case. Big-O complexity is typically expressed in the average terms over the domain of possible cases and then, for Python, and sets, it is O(n) average. Please see [the details.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)